# Multiple Tooltips to same Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip

I am using Windows Forms Application in C#
I have a label having Date as Text **16-12-2010**
Now I want to display different Tooltip when mouse is over Date/Month/Year

e.g. When Cursor on **Date** : Then **Today's Date**
 as Tooltip

**UPDATED:**

> One Source of Example is When we vote
>   to Close any Question in
>   StackOverflow.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use multiple labels - one for each part.

Otherwise you're going to need to know which characters in the Label the mouse is over - different Font's render differently. That's a can-o-worms if ever there was one.

Answer (score 0):

You can beak the label in 3 labels and set the tool tips as you like.